# Delete multiple nodes of the same name

Tags: python, lxml

Suppose I have an XML tree as following:

```
my_data.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>    
  <country name="Singapore" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama" xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
    <maylay>
      <holidays>ramadan</holidays>
      <holidays>eid al fitri</holidays>
    </malay>
  </ethnicity>
</data>
```

Parsing the tree with `lxml`:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xtree = etree.parse('my_data.xml')
xroot = xtree.getroot()
```

```
malay_node = xroot.xpath('.//*[local-name()="malay"]')[0]
malay_holiday_nodes = xroot.xpath('.//*[local-name()="holidays"]')
```

I want to delete simultaneously all the `holidays` nodes under node `malay`. Note that `malay_holiday_nodes` is a `list`. If I do this:

```
malay_node.remove(malay_holiday_nodes)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got list)
```

Any simple way to remove the whole list of child nodes like this without a `for` loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to using XSLT (which I'm a big fan and user of) is to use lxml's [`strip_elements()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_elements)...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("my_data.xml")

etree.strip_elements(tree, "{*}holidays", with_tail=True)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

Output ("output.xml") using your sample XML with the maylay/malay tag mismatch fixed...

```xml
<data>
  <country xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:singapore:eee" name="Singapore">
    <continent>Asia</continent>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:panama:eee" name="Panama">
    <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
  <ethnicity xmlns="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
    <malay>
      </malay>
  </ethnicity>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/) the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Specifically, an identity template and empty `malay` template can remove the needed nodes all without a single `for` loop. Python's `lxml` library can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special XML file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE TO REMOVE CONTENT -->
    <xsl:template match="doc:malay/*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4T)</kbd>

**Python**

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.xml")
style = lx.parse("Style.xsl")

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open("Output.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: Excellent answer as always Parfait. Just a couple of observations...in your XSLT you're removing the entire `malay` element. I read the question as wanting to only remove the children of `malay`. Also, `malay` is in a namespace so the XSLT won't do anything with the current input. Maybe change the match to `e:malay/*` (or whatever prefix) and bind the prefix to `aaa:bbb:ccc:ethnicity:eee`.

Comment: In the python instead of opening a file object to write, you can just do [`result.write_output("Output.xml")`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree-class.html#write_output) but you'll need to specify the encoding in the `xsl:output` in the stylesheet. Makes the python a tiny bit cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for the tip on XSLT. Something new for me to pick up in the long run. Daniel Haley's Python solution seems to work for me immediately, though.

Comment: No problem. I adjusted XSLT with online demo link to show. Happy coding!