# Removing the same element across all the nodes of an XML tree

Tags: python-3.x, xml

For example sake, this is the xml file that I'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        <description>Liechtenstein has a lot of flowers.</description>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        <description>Singapore has a lot of street markets.</description>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
        <description>Panama has a lot of great food.</description>
    </country>
</data>
```

How would I write the code such that I could delete one node element (i.e. year or description) across each of the country nodes. For example, in the following code:

```
# To remove 
# for country in root.findall('country'):
    # year = int(country.find('year').text)
    # if year > 2010:
        # root.remove(country)
# tree.write('sample.xml')
```

I can remove any country nodes whose attribute of the element year is greater than 2010. But that removes the entire node, not just the year element. I know that I can remove a single element of a node with the following:

```
# for country in root.findall('country'):
    # description_node = country.find('description')
    # if description_node.text == "Singapore has a lot of street markets.":
        # country.remove(description_node)
# tree.write('sample.xml')
```

But now I want to create a condition where I delete the description element or the year element or the neighbor element throughout all of the country nodes present.

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: Are you using lxml or ElementTree? If lxml, you could just use [`strip_elements`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_elements). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69008043/317052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be the following that uses `.findall` and `.remove`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = 'source.xml'
data = ET.parse(file)

for country in data.findall('country'):
    for neighbor in country.findall('neighbor'):
        country.remove(neighbor)
    for year in country.findall('year'):
        country.remove(year)
    for description in country.findall('description'):
        country.remove(description)

ET.dump(data)
```

Output:

```
python yourscript.py 
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        </country>
</data>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much. Do you know how I would remove "excessive whitespaces"? For example, what if in the original xml file, in the description element, there were just so more header and traililng whitespaces in the description. 

This was my code: 
# Remove whitespace for each element in the tree
for elem in root.iter():
    elem.text = elem.text.strip()
    elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()

Comment: Glad the proposed solution works for you.  And yes, I believe utilizing `elem.text = elem.text.strip()` and `elem.tail = elem.tail.strip()` should suffice to trim leading and trailing whitespace from the element's text and from the text follwing an element's closing tag and the next tag.  You should mark this question as answered and open a separate question regarding stripping whitespace if you are having issues there.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do, for example:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="year[. > 2000]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

The empty template rule causes elements that match the predicate to be removed; the xsl:mode instruction causes everything else to be retained.